# How to create custom styles for annotated elements

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to find a way to mark usages of annotated elements with a different color and a strike through like

```java
@Deprecated
```

does on its own. 
What I want to accomplish is a "Don't Use this" annotation that says that this element shouldn't be used (like deprecated). So far I have found nothing that does that.

Answer (score 0):

Create [custom inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-custom-inspections.html) based on [Structural Search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html) for which you specify your custom annotation and use it in project to highlight such usages.

Comment: I cant seem to reference the method calls after that tho, I tried following the existing templates from IDEA of deprecated and deprecated calls.